# Posting String and Arrays in Volley?

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I was wondering how one is supposed to post string and array via POST in getParams in Volley.

Any suggestions would be great.

EG:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("dob", dob);
                for (int i=0; i< array_list_likes.size(); i++) {
                    params.put("likes["+i+"]", array_list_likes.get(i));
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do this you post String and Array**

```
 protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("name", name);
                    params.put("username", username);
                    params.put("email", email);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    params.put("dob", dob);
                    JSONArray jsonArrayLikes  = new JSONArray();
                    for (int i=0; i< array_list_likes.size(); i++) {
                     JSONObject jsonLikes = new JSONObject();
                        jsonLikes .put("likes", array_list_likes.get(i).getLikes());
                       jsonArrayLikes.put(jsonLikes);
                     }
                 params.put("likes" , jsonArrayLikes.toString());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("email", email);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("dob", dob);
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
    for (int i=0; i< array_list_likes.size(); i++) {
         arr[i]= array_list_likes.get(i).getLikes();
         jsonObject.put("likes["+i+"]",arr[i]);
    }
    params.put("params",jsonObject.toString());
    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array can be converted as String and pass along with the other params as follows and convert the String to array in server side by using a seperator `,`

This may not be the best way but its a simple way

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

   Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
   params.put("name", name);
   params.put("username", username);
   params.put("email", email);
   params.put("password", password);
   params.put("dob", dob);

   params.put("likes", String.valueOf(array_list_likes));
}
```

It all Depends on Server side if You Write your Own Web Services This Way u can convert Array to String ,But if your are passing to Existing web Service Code
You can try other.

Hope it helps you